When negating, do you flip the signs always?
$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \exists L \in \mathbb{R},\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$
when negating this, I understand we flip the forall and exists sign, but do we flip all inequality signs? $$\text{Particularly}, \forall \epsilon > 0 \text{ negation becomes } \exists \epsilon \leq 0$$
Am I correct?

No. Consider an example. The statement
$$
(\forall x > 0)(|x|=x) \tag{1}
$$
has negation
$$
(\exists x > 0)(|x| \ne x) \tag{2}
$$
And this should make sense: if $(1)$ is false, then it means there is some $x$ in the domain of concern where $|x|=x$ does not hold. We don't care about the case of $x < 0$ or $x=0$, even in $(2)$, since a counterexample to $(1)$ still needs to have $x>0$.

You might be "happier" thinking "$\forall \varepsilon > 0$" is "$\forall \varepsilon \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$".  The "$>0$" isn't part of the proposition -- it's part of the domain on which the proposition is defined.

No. $$\forall\epsilon>0\quad P(\epsilon)$$
is a shorthand for
$$\forall\epsilon\quad[\epsilon>0\implies P(\epsilon)]$$
hence its negation is not $\exists\epsilon\le0\quad\neg P(\epsilon)$
but
$$\exists\epsilon\quad[\epsilon>0\land\neg P(\epsilon)]$$
or for short:
$$\exists\epsilon>0\quad\neg P(\epsilon).$$
For more details, see this post.

Thanks! This exact question came up on my midterm, so you really saved me there!

No. If $P$ is a proposition, $$\forall \epsilon > 0 : P$$ is short for $$\forall \epsilon : (\epsilon > 0 \implies P)$$ so the negation is $$\exists \epsilon : \neg(\epsilon >0 \implies P)$$ or equivalently $$\exists\epsilon:(\epsilon > 0 \wedge \neg P)$$
which is usually written for short as $$\exists \epsilon>0:\neg P$$

@AnneBauval beat me to write practically the same answer

The resemblance of the two answers is impressive
